# mulitiple loops and/or iterations

Tags: loops, sql-insert, plpgsql

I'm trying to loop on the EXECUTE into rowcnt.  I am grouping on year and need to insert for each record.  I am succesfully looping through the For rec, but only inserting 1 row per table with mc_id = 2

````
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE 
  rec RECORD;
  rec2 RECORD;
  sch text;
  tbl text;
  fld text;
  qry text;
  rowcnt RECORD;
   BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM AUDIT.AUDIT_METRIC_DEFINITIONS WHERE metric_class_id = mc_id
    LOOP
      sch = quote_ident(rec.schema_name);
      fld = quote_ident(rec.field_name);
      tbl = quote_ident(rec.schema_name)||'.'||quote_ident(rec.table_name);
      qry := 'select extract(year from '||fld||') as yr, count(*) as cnt from '|| tbl ||' group by 1';
      EXECUTE qry into rowcnt;
      INSERT INTO AUDIT.AUDIT_METRIC_DATA(metric_id,level,value,run_date) values(rec.metric_id,tbl||'.'||fld||'.'||rowcnt.yr,rowcnt.cnt,current_date);
    END LOOP;
END
$$; ```
````

Comment: How is the behavior exhibited different than what you are wanting to accomplish?

Comment: I am able to loop through the rec record set.  However, for each table that I query, I want to insert the year and the record count.  As it is written now, only 1 record, from rowcnt, per table is inserted, rather than 1 record for each year for each table.  I need an additional loop to insert each record from rowcnt which is grouped by year.

Comment: Hope that make sense